# How to feed a non-bound form field with data?

Tags: django

Previously I had a separate Time Field and a Date Field in my Model, which I am now trying to join into one DateTime field, due timezone issues.

```
class Conversation(models.Model):
    conversation_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
```

In my form I created two new fields one for time and another for date in order to extract the datetime in each accordingly.

```
class CallsForm(ModelForm):       
    conversation_date = forms.DateField(localize=True, widget=forms.DateInput())
    conversation_time = forms.TimeField(localize=True, widget=forms.TimeInput())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CallsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['conversation_date'] = self.instance.conversation_datetime.date()
        self.fields['conversation_time'] = self.instance.conversation_datetime.time()
```

In my view I simply pass in the instance:

```
call = Conversation(conversation_datetime = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc))
form = CallsForm(instance=call)
```

However in my template the fields don't get rendered. If I comment out the two rows in `__init__`, it gets perfectly rendered. What is wrong here?

```
   # self.fields['conversation_date'] = self.instance.conversation_datetime.date()
   # self.fields['conversation_time'] = self.instance.conversation_datetime.time()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You override your form fields. Probably you want to set initial value:

```
self.fields['conversation_date'].initial = self.instance.conversation_datetime.date()
self.fields['conversation_time'].initial = self.instance.conversation_datetime.time()
```